# Conda, r-base, and X11 on macOS

Tags: python, r, macos, rstudio, x11

I am relatively new to data science and I want the flexibility to leverage the strengths of R within a Python environment. However, I could not find a way to get X11 working in an R/Rstudio environment managed by conda on macOS.

Is there any way to build r-base with X11 enabled using conda on macOS? Is this even necessary when using R within Python via rpy2?

I tried installing xquartz via Homebrew and doing a fresh install of an R environment afterwards. I also tried installing xquartz directly from xquartz.org (after removing xquartz via Homebrew) and doing a fresh install of an R environment after. Both attempts failed in getting X11 enabled after checking via `capabilities()` in rstudio.

I finally was able to get X11 working in Rstudio after separately installing Rstudio and R from their respective sources without using conda.